# Trying to add formula directly to a cell in VBA and it disappears?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an input form where someone puts in numbers and clicks submit so it records on a table. I realized I want to have one cell on the input sheet calculate a percent automatically instead of having to calculate it manually. The problem is that every time I enter the formula and then use the clear macro, the formula disappears instead of just the value within. I have other cells with formulas that this does not happen to so I am assuming there is some way to fix it and make it like the others. In the code it is using

```
Range("ccmcocc").ClearContents
```

just like the others with formulas.

Comment: `ClearContents` clears formulas too.... From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearcontents): "Clears formulas and values from the range"

Comment: You probably need to show a bit more of your code. There's no method for clearing a formula output while keeping the formula intact: instead you need to code the formula such that when you clear the formula *inputs*, the output is empty.